# Inactive Button Presses (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
String tempNum="";
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
    {
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();  
        if(src.equals(one))  
        {
            if (pressed + 3000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) // user press > 3 seconds
            {
                tempNum = tempNum + "1";
                //do a command
            }
            else //new 
            {
                pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
                tempNum="";
                tempNum = tempNum + "1";
                //do a command
            }
        }
}
```

Hello. In this program, the user will be pressing a `JButton one`. Users who continuously press `one` within 3 seconds with append the string "1" to `tempNum`. When the user presses another `one` after 3 seconds, the `tempNum` will just have a value of "1".
My question is: Initially, when the user presses a brand new "1", how do you detect if the user is inactive for 3 seconds?

For example:

Input:
User input: 1

How do you detect if the user didn't press anything after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Declare Long pressed = null; The initial value of it will be null, which tells that the user hasn't yet pressed a button.

```
/**
 * Declare pressed as Long pressed = null; in your code for the following to work as intended.
 */

StringBuilder tempNum = new StringBuilder(); 
String   TO_ADD   = "1"; 
int      presses  =  0 ;
int      SECONDS  =  3 ; 

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    JButton src       = (JButton) event.getSource();  
    /**
     * Do call System.currentTimeMillis() once at the beginning and store it's value as later calls System.currentTimeMillis() could return later time.
     */
    long    pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if(src.equals(one))  
    {
        /**
         * No press was done
         */
        if (null == pressed)
        {
            pressed = pressTime;
        }

        if (pressed + SECONDS*1000 > pressTime) // user press > 3 seconds
        {
            presses++;
            //do a command
        }
        else //new 
        {
            pressed = pressTime;
            presses = 1        ;
            tempNum = new StringBuilder();
            //do a command
        }
        tempNum.append(TO_ADD); //to get string call tempNum.toString(); in your code
    }
}
```